# Rectangles Ovals Digitizing Plugin error in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, polygon-creation

I am using **Rectangles Ovals Digitizing** plugin in QGIS 2.18.2 for macOS. What I noticed is when using the `Rectangle by extent tool` it creates two layers so I have duplicate layers or features with duplicate geometries.
Is this a bug or I have to change something on shapefile layer properties?

Note: To remove duplicate I am currently using `MMQGIS> Delete Duplicate Geometries`. But I want to remove the error while creating the boxes.
Also any other plugin which can create Bounding boxes/ Rectangles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found why this was happening. After creation of a rectangle Feature Attribute Dialog opens up and we have enter an ID. If we cancel that then only one feature is created. If we add ID then there will be duplicate entry. 
So there are two ways to stop this.

1. Press Cancel when the Dialog comes up
2. Disable the popup by Going to **Settings> Options > Digitizing > Under Feature Creation >** Checking **Supress attribute form pop-up after feature creation**
   this will remove the popup dialog which comes after creating any shape of feature.